# Reactjs app build size taking too much space

Tags: reactjs, performance, build, chunks

I have used code splitting in my app to reduce bundle size. In my build folder it contains 20-30 chunks files and also each chunk has [name].chunk.js.map which is taking too much space. How we can reduce the build folder size. The total size of build folder is around 107 Mb.

Code Splitting:

```
/**
 * AsyncComponent
 * Code Splitting Component / Server Side Rendering
 */
import React from 'react';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

// Abc page loader
import AbcPageLoader from '../AbcPageLoader/AbcPageLoader';

// dashboard
const AsyncDashboardComponent = Loadable({
    loader: () => import("../../routes/dashboard/dashboard-v1"),
    loading: () => <AbcPageLoader />,
});

// widgets
const AsyncWidgetsComponent = Loadable({
    loader: () => import("../../routes/widgets"),
    loading: () => <AbcPageLoader />,
});

export { AsyncDashboardComponent, AsyncWidgetsComponent  };
```

Comment: Can you give some more detail about what you've tried so far, what kind of tools you're using, what is causing your bundle to be so large right now, etc?

Comment: You can use ```Code Splitting``` if you are using ```react-router```:
https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/code-splitting-in-create-react-app.html

Comment: #AdamBerman I have used react-loadable package for code splitting. https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue after some research on webpack. The bundle size is too large due to the source-map. I have add the GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false in webpack.prod.config.js and resolved this issue.

Comment: Source maps are only there to make it easier to debug in e.g. the chrome debugger, and they are not downloaded until you open the console. Normal users get the optimized file. It's pretty much just you and the occasional curious user who will download them.
Also, if you're configuring webpack yourself (not e.g. create-react-app), make sure you're using [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/), as well as using selective imports in your code. E.g. `import { keyBy } from 'lodash'` instead of `import lodash from 'lodash'; lodash.keyBy(...` copies far less into your bundle.